# Вычислить сколько определенных элементов поблизости для другого определенного элемента в списке?

Tags: python, list, count

Хотелось бы посчитать сколько 'x' поблизости для'.' ('.' - здесь как клетка)

```
[
['x', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.']
['.', 'x', 'x']
['.', '.', '.']
]
```

результат:

```
[
['x', '1', '0']
['2', '3', '2']
['1', 'x', 'x']
['1', '2', '2']
]
```

Я пытался сделать что-то, но в результате получаю только ноль:

```
def count(list, row, col):
    count = 0
    if list[row][col] == 'x':
        for row in range(row - 1, row + 2):
            for col in range(col - 1, col + 2):
                count += 1
    return count
```

может надо ещё каких-то условий или у меня просто неправильная логика?

Comment: Условие `if list[row][col] == 'x':` неправильное, должен быть `'.'` вместо `'x'` или оно вообще не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать numpy

```
# исходная матрица
m = np.array(m)
# делаем маску шире и выше на 2, чтобы окружить нулями
mask = np.zeros((m.shape[0]+2,m.shape[1]+2))
# и такой же размерности массив под суммы
s = m.copy()
# середину маски заполняем 1 на местах мин :)
mask[1:-1,1:-1] = (m=='x').astype(int)

// подвигаем верх-вниз и влево-вправо
for axis in [0,1]:
    for sign in [1,-1]:
        s += np.roll(mask.copy(),sign,axis)

// а теперь по диагоналям
for x in [1,-1]:
    for y in [1,-1]:
        s += np.roll(mask.copy(),(x,y), (0,1))

// осталось оформить ответ
s = s[1:-1,1:-1]
np.where(m=='x', 'x', s.astype(int).astype(str))

array([['x', '1', '0'],
       ['2', '3', '2'],
       ['1', 'x', 'x'],
       ['1', '2', '2']],
       dtype='<U11')
```

---

А можно и не использовать

```
def count(m, row, col):
    if m[row][col] == 'x' :
        return 'x'
    # слайс по рядам
    temp = m[(row-1 if row else 0):row+2]
    # в каждом ряду в слайсе  по колонке считаем количество "х",
    # а потом всё это складываем 
    return str(sum(map(lambda x: sum(i=='x' for i in x[(col-1 if col else 0):col+2]), temp)))
```