# Не понимаю, почему в результате на одно число меньше или больше

Tags: python, list, count

Мой код для вычисления, сколько 'x' или 'X' поблизости для '.'

```
def count(list, row, col):
    count = 0
    for row in range((row - 1 if row > 0 else row), (row + 2 if row < (len(list) - 1) else row + 1)):
        for col in range((col - 1 if col > 0 else col), (col + 2 if col < (len(list[0]) - 1) else col + 1)):
            if list[row][col] in ('x', 'X'):
                count += 1
    return count

def calculate_x_count(list):
    for row in range(len(list)):
        for col in range(len(list[0])):
            if list[row][col] == '.':
                list[row][col] = str(count(list, row, col))
    return list
```

Лист, который я использую для проверки:

```
list = [['x', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'x', 'x'], ['.', '.', '.']]
```

Результат, который должен быть:

```
[['x', '1', '0'], ['2', '3', '2'], ['1', 'x', 'x'], ['1', '2', '2']]
```

Результат, который я получаю:

```
[['x', '1', '0'], ['3', '3', '2'], ['2', 'x', 'x'], ['1', '2', '2']]
```

Comment: хочу подметить, что не стоит обзывать переменные именами встроенных типов, вроде list, dict, tuple, set и тд.

Comment: Вот прям сегодня отвечал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037240/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB/1037290#1037290

Comment: @splash58 я видел, но я решил сделать по-своему, и почти вышло, и одновременно не вышло

Comment: Да что там может получаться не получаться, распечатайте параметры слайсов, по идее, ошибка только тут и может быть. Мне с телефона неудобно смотреть, я так - предполагаю )

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, как сделать это - вдруг кому-то интересно или нужно:

```
def count(list, row, col):
    count = 0
    for h in range((row - 1 if row > 0 else row), (row + 2 if row < (len(list) - 1) else row + 1)):
        for w in range((col - 1 if col > 0 else col), (col + 2 if col < (len(list[0]) - 1) else col + 1)):
            if list[h][w] == 'x' or list[h][w] == 'X'::
                count += 1
    return count
```

и всё работает в итоге